# Sublime Text - A more selective "match selection" tool?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I'm currently using the "match_selection" feature in Sublime Text that comes set up by default. If highlight a word, Sublime will highlight "other occurrences of the currently selected text." It works if I'm looking for matching in terms of spelling. However, I'd like a more selective 'match selector' that'll only match the word if its the same exact data type.

I'll include an image. Here I select the word **first** in the parameters on line 3. If it was truly grabbing exact matches it should only be highlighting those two other occurrences of **first** to the right of the equals sign, yet it grabs the **first** in self.first as well as the **first** in the string, even though they aren't the same data type/variable

It does not do this in PyCharm. Is there a package that would solve this?

[image]